# Grace period issue for cached POST request on Varnish 6

Tags: post, caching, varnish

We are using Varnish 6. We successfully cached "POST" requests sends for graphql
TTL is 120second
Grace: 1 hour

When TTL is over, but still in grace period, Varnish is not trigger post request to backend server behind the scene. in somehow, Varnish is again asking for backend and mean while end user is waiting for this process.

How we can make sure Varnish can auto-trigger cached POST requests as well in Grace period.

Answer (score 0):

An expired object that has some grace time left will trigger a backend fetch. This is by design.

The only way to avoid any backend fetch is by increasing the TTL. The only reason grace mode exists is to ensure users don't have to wait for expired content while Varnish is fetching it asynchronously.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlPNEnQny7o for a video about the lifetime of an object in Varnish (which includes TTL, grace & keep).

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51WUTB1cUeM for a dedicated video about grace mode.